# Spring Security Test with custom filter gives 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, mockmvc

I implemented a custom Spring Boot security filter that performs additional checks to the JWT one.

I created this custom configuration:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthGatewayFilter authGatewayFilter;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain auth0FilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .addFilterAt(authGatewayFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().build();
    }
}
```

And the authentication filter is made this way (it is an example, the real filter is more complex):

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AuthGatewayFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication;
            authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("principal@springboot.com", null, null);
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

So I wanted to test this security and used MockMVC. Unfortunately, the test always gives me a 401 instead of 200:

```java
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class Auth0IntegrationControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void securityCheckWithOkta() throws Exception {
        String jwt = "...";
        mockMvc.perform(
                        get("/security-check")
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                                .header("companyId", 1438)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

How can I solve it? May I edit the MockMVC?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@WithMockUser` with your username so it will set Authentication into context.

```
  @WithMockUser(username = "principal@springboot.com")
@SneakyThrows
@Test
void securityCheckWithOkta() throws Exception {
    String jwt = "...";
    mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/security-check")
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                            .header("companyId", 1438)
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
}
```